# Is it overfitting if I am using predictions from cross-validation as a level 2 feature for stacking model?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, predictive-models, prediction, ensemble-learning

I am learning how to stack models, but I am worried if this is not a practical way to do it. I am using the full dataset and using `cross_val_predict` to get the output from the level 1 models. Then, I will be using the output as the feature for level 2 model. Again, I am using `cross_val_predict` and the output are the final predictions.

Is this causing overfitting?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what `cross_val_predict` is doing, or what its output is. Could you describe the actual steps being taken in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Your level 1 models are exposed to each training instance in your data set as the learn their weights/coefficients.

You then train your level 2 model based on results from your level 1 models.  This is fine, except when you perform your cross-validation a second time, the level 2 model is now exposed to the data in the hold-out set, because the level 1 models were exposed to that data when they were trained.

Your ideal method would be the following:

1 - set aside your hold-out set for validation

2 - train your level 1 models

3 - train your level 2 model

4 - test the stacked model on your hold-out set

5 - repeat 1-4 with new hold-out set.